# Javascript Regex -restrict +,- in middle of the regex

Tags: javascript, regex

```
function btnNumber(){
        charTyped=document.getElementById('txtNumber').value;
        var NumberplusminusRegex =/^[\+?\-?\d]+$/g;

        if (charTyped.match(NumberplusminusRegex)) {
            alert('yeah');
            return true;

        }
        else {
            alert('whoa');
            return false;

        }

}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/27630/)

This is my function to restrict the input in number and +,- sign but how to restrict it at middle i.e at the end +,- is good to go but at middle it will not

Comment: Maybe `/^[-+]?\d+[-+]?$/` will do? Here, a `+` or `-` are optional at the beginning and end of the string. Or, if the signs are allowed only at the start OR only at end, try `/^([-+]?\d+|\d+[-+]?)$/`.

Comment: Thanks it is working

Comment: Inputs and expected outputs would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting the `\+?\-?` into the character class just allows `+`, or `-` or `?` inside the string.

If you need to allow  a `+` or `-` at the beginning and end of the string, use

```
/^[-+]?\d+[-+]?$/
  ^^^^^   ^^^^^
```

The `[-+]?` matches either `+` or `-` *one or zero times* (due to the `?` quantifier).

Or, if the signs are allowed only at the start OR only at end, use

```
/^([-+]?\d+|\d+[-+]?)$/
```

Pattern details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - Group start

  - `[-+]?` - 1 or 0 `-` or `+`
  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
  - `|` - or
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `[-+]?` -  1 or 0 `-` or `+`
- `)` - end of group
- `$` - end of string.

Also, to check if a string matches a pattern, it is advisable to use `RegExp#test` rather than `String#match`:

```
var NumberplusminusRegex =/^[-+]?\d+[-+]?$/;
if (NumberplusminusRegex.test(charTyped)) { // Yes, else no
```

```js
function btnNumber(){
charTyped=document.getElementById('txtNumber').value;
    var NumberplusminusRegex =/^[-+]?\d+[-+]?$/;    // NOTE /g should not be used with RegExp.test()
    if (NumberplusminusRegex.test(charTyped)) {     // Check if a match is found
        alert('yeah');
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert('whoa');
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="btnNumber()">Click me</button>
<input type='text' id='txtNumber'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression
`var NumberplusminusRegex = "/^[+-]?[0-9]+$/g";`